# Copying a text file into debug directory

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Working with c++ fstream in visual studio, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to include specific files in my debug folder (or any build folder really). I know in c# there's an option to "always copy to path" or something along those lines, so that I can use a relative path (ex: "fileName.txt") easily. I'm just wondering if there's an equivalent in c++, or if I'm stuck building the full path and using that?

Comment: You could copy the files to the output as a post-build event.

Comment: @MariusBancila yea, I figured as much, I was just wondering if there was a way to always make sure it was in the same directory without manually doing it.